# Reading maps in yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I have the following yaml file:

```
Pantalla:
ancho: 640
alto: 480

Configuracion:
    vel_personaje: 3
    merge_scroll: 30

Tipos:
    - nombre: arbol
      imagen: img/tree
      ancho_base: 2
      alto_base: 2
      pixel_ref_x: 30
      pixel_ref_y: 40
      fps: 10
      delay: 5

    - nombre: casa
      imagen: img/house

    - nombre: auto
      imagen: img/car
      ancho_base: 5
      alto_base: 5

Escenario:
    - nombre: principal
      size_x: 100
      size_y: 100
      entidades:  
           ­- {x: 10, y: 15, tipo: tierra}
           ­- {x: 15, y: 20, tipo: tierra}
           ­- {x: 10, y: 15, tipo: agua} 
         ­  - {x: 30, y: 55, tipo: castillo}
    protagonista:
        - tipo: principal
          x: 50
          y: 50
```

When I tried to read the different "entidades", the yaml-cpp says the following:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YAML::ParserException'
>     what():  yaml-cpp: error at line 32, column 25: illegal map value

Line 32 column 25 is just after "y: ". I don't know that I'm doing wrong. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dash in line 28 is `\u00ad`, which is "soft hyphen". I think it should be like this:

```
Escenario:
    nombre: principal
    size_x: 100
    size_y: 100
    entidades:  
        ­- {x: 10, y: 15, tipo: tierra}
    ­    - {x: 15, y: 20, tipo: tierra}
    ­    - {x: 10, y: 15, tipo: agua}
    ­    - {x: 30, y: 55, tipo: castillo}
    protagonista:
        - tipo: principal
          x: 50
          y: 50
          y: 50
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is not the problem. I removed that hyphen and the error is still happening. Also, I used http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ and it says "mapping values are not allowed here" But still don't know why.. Thanks for any future help! @jesse-beder

Comment: @user2566343 you have a lot of strange characters in your file. Find a hex editor and make sure that spaces are really spaces and hyphens are really hyphens.